# How send data to the server without XMLHttpRequest in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, browser

I have read about that there is some other way to send small chunk of data (mostly tracking information) to the server than using ajax (or fetch). It omits the response from the server. And the browser send this asynchronously, when it has an opportunity to do so, without delaying the unload or affecting the performance of the next navigation

I think it was something like `navigator.theMethod(url, data);`

Does somebody know what I am talking about?

Comment: Well... there are different ways, all more complex than ajax. The smaller the data you've to send, the less the necessity to use something different from ajax, except for security issue. The most common are "web services" (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_servicehttps://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

Comment: This method was created to be more simple than ajax.

Comment: The only thing that would perhaps automatically notify of a page unload would be the closure of a websocket by the u/a.

Comment: You may be thinking of window.onunload, which doesn't do what you're thinking. There is no such method other than a websocket disconnecting to notify the server that the page is being closed without an http request.

Comment: You can use it in the window.onunload event because the browser supposed to handle it regardless from the state of the the actual window. So it will send the data to the specified address after closing of the tab too. But the question is not really about the detection of a tab close. So this is off topic here.

I start to believe that it was a dream only, strange that I cant google it, and no one else heard about it. Lol

Comment: I found the answer. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The method is called `navigator.sendBeacon()`

The old method is to submit data to a server by using a synchronous XMLHttpRequest or loading an image in an unload handler. This results in the unload of the page to be delayed.

> Using the sendBeacon() method, the data will be transmitted asynchronously to the web server when the User Agent has had an opportunity to do so, without delaying the unload or affecting the performance of the next navigation.

Here is a minimal sample usage:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', logData, false);

function logData() {
    navigator.sendBeacon("/log", analyticsData);
}
```

This is the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) about it

Comment: The usual suspects, safari and IE, do not support this

Comment: Latest Safari supports it now, however, I think it's safe to say that IE never will.

Answer (score 1):

You can open some URL in iframe or set this URL as image source.
For example:

```
var image = document.createElement( 'img' ),
    iframe = document.createElement( 'iframe' );

image.src = '/some/url?with=parameters';
iframe.src = '/some/url?with=parameters';
```

But you won't receive any data in response

Comment: I know this method. The one I am looking for was designed to be more simple and make the workarounds unnecessary . If I recall correctly :) (Its strange that I cant find it. )

Comment: Why is this a workaround?

Comment: Because its not the usage it was intended to do so. I found the solution, check my answer.